# guardar nombre de imagen en base de datos de laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy intentando guardar el nombre de la imagen en base de datos desde Laravel, pude obtener el nombre del archivo pero me sale error en el código:

```
$name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

y pues no se cual es el error lo que tengo hasta ahorita es para guardar la imagen en una ruta del laravel, y ver que sale pero obviamente no funciona por el error :

```
if ($file = $request->foto){

     $file = $request->file('foto');
     $file = $request->foto;
     $name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

     dd($name);

  }
```

como lo puedo solucuiona?

Comment: Añade una captura del error

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = $request->file('file');
            //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
            $nombre =  time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            //indicamos que queremos guardar un nuevo archivo en el disco local
            \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre,  \File::get($file));

            $archivo = new Archivos;
            $archivo->nombre_ = $nombre;
            $archivo->save();
```

espero te sirva así yo lo hago guardo el nombre y el archivo